# Nodejs Postgress Error no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm creating a new `pool` object a follows:

```
import { Pool, PoolConfig } from "pg";

const options = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: Number.parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT as any),
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  connectionLimit: Number.parseInt(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT as any),
  ssl: false,
} as PoolConfig;

export const pool = new Pool(options);
```

But when i try to do `pool.query` I'm getting the following error:

```
"There was an error processing your request: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"172.31.0.1\", user \"admin\", database \"todos\", no encryption"
```

I've also tried to set the `ssl` to true but it seems not working.

What maybe posibly the problem here

Comment: The server you're trying to connect to is rejecting your IP. Or in other words, Postgres isn't configured to listen to `172.31.0.1`. You need to configure postgres permissions. There are many answers to this question so you should pick which works best for you. Depending on the environment you can set `listen_addresses = *` or specify allowed IP addresses in `/etc/postgresql/<version_number>/pg_hba.conf`